# Tracking install app without analytics SDK?

Tags: ios, swift

We have our own analytics service. How can you track app installs or get utm tags inside the app (after installing from the appStore via a dedicated link) **without** installing any SDK (Google Analytics, etc.)?
iOS 13+, swift 5.

Comment: If you have your own analytics back-end can you not make a once-only call on first run (with internet connection) ?  Or do you want something else?

Comment: Yep. We would like to know for sure that the application is installed and the response to the server should be sent only after a certain period of time after installation.

Comment: That’s your domain to control.  :-)  as in  `if  myCriteriaAreMet then POST firstRunStuffToBackend` . You can create any timers and conditions that you need to.

Comment: Perhaps I incorrectly described the problem ... There is a referral link and it is required to send information to the backend only about downloads via it.